# vertical/horizontal centering inside fixed element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a fixed overlay (full screen) on my Wordpress website. I want the element inside the fixed div to be horiz/vert center. All the examples I could find have the parent set to relative but the height and width have to set to 100%.

html

```
<div class="overlay">
    <nav class="menu">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
    </nav>   
</div>
```

css

```
.overlay{
position: fixed;
display: none;
z-index: 50;
top: 0; left: 0;
height: 100%; width: 100%;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
overflow: auto;
}

.menu {

}
```

I tried using y/x-translate but the parent had to be relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a container for your nav element and set it into position relative, so that the child element nav would be on position absolute, and by that you can center position your navigation with the overlay.

**HTML**

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="menu">
      <a>One</a>
      <a>Two</a>
      <a>Three</a>
    </nav>   
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay{
position: fixed;
z-index: 50;
top: 0; left: 0;
height: 100%; width: 100%;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
overflow: auto;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  position: relative;  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5nmrdbhL/

Comment: ok cool, that's close, can it be centered center? right now the left side is centered

Comment: You should adjust the left, and right properties in .menu class to make it centered.